# GPS in Processing

Tags: processing

I doing a small program using [Processing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Processing_%28programming_language%29), and it's basically a map of Europe and a question will ask where a certain capital is in Europe. For example, if the question is where Milan is and the person clicks on Madrid I want to use a GPS to calculate the distance between Milan and Madrid. So hopefully the output would be "You have clicked on the wrong city. You are xxx miles away from Milan".

How do I code for this?

Comment: what way could i do it then. Its part of a college project which was given to me and was told to try use the gps but what other way can it be done

Comment: This isn't a site where you go to get people to do your work for you...

Comment: GPS gives you nanosecond-precision time-of-day, not the distance between two points.

Answer (score 1):

You definitely don't need a GPS for that, in fact a GPS won't even do what you want.  All you need is the coordinates of the capitals for which you will ask the location.  Presumably you can get this as latitude and longitude, although since you're displaying them on the screen, perhaps you will just get their x/y coordinates from whatever image/display you are using.

Lets assume you have an x and y for a city, and a click on the screen. The distance between two points on a plane is probably something you learned in high school geometry.  The equation is available [on Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cartesian_coordinate_system#Distance_between_two_points).

If for some reason, you need to calculate the distance between two points of latitude/longitude, that's a little more complicated, and probably not worth it, but it's doable -- in fact, the [question has been asked on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27928/how-do-i-calculate-distance-between-two-latitude-longitude-points).

That should be enough to get you started.  If not, you should probably flesh your question out with some details.